# How to trigger right mouse click event handler in Word 2016?

Tags: vba, events, ms-word, handler

I have VBA code which uses the right click of the mouse in a Word file.
I use the event handler to take out the typical right click menu.

In class module:

```vb
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application
    
Public Sub appWord_WindowBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sel As Selection, Cancel As Boolean)
    cancel=true 'in this way I avoided the menu of word-right button mouse to be shown.
End Sub
```

In a normal module:

```vb
Dim X As New Class1
    
Public Sub Register_Event_Handler()
    Set X.appWord = Word.Application
End Sub
```

The working sub:

```vb
Public Sub tipo1()
    Register_Event_Handler
    colorseleccion = 0
    tiposeleccion = 1
    seleccionatextoslevel1
End Sub
```

In Word 2010, when clicking the right mouse button it didn't show the menu, so by *GetAsyncKeyState* I was able to do what I wanted.

In Word 2016, the program does what it is supposed to do when clicking the right mouse button, but in addition the typical menu when clicking the right button is shown. This means that the event handler is not working anymore.

I suspect that some option in the configuration is blocking the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work on **Office 2016** (tested on 2013 and it works):

> 1. Create a new **class module** and name it: `cRightClickEventHandler`. Copy this code:

```
Public WithEvents oApp As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set oApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub oApp_WindowBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sel As Selection, Cancel As Boolean)
    CreateCommand
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

> 2. Insert new **module**, copy paste code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const sCommName As String = "Custom"

Public cApp As cRightClickEventHandler

Sub CreateCommand()
Dim cb As CommandBar
Dim ctr As CommandBarControl

On Error GoTo Err_CreateCommand

KillCommand

Set cb = Application.CommandBars.Add(sCommName, msoBarPopup)
Set ctr = cb.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
With ctr
    .Caption = "Let's do it!"
    .TooltipText = .Caption
    .FaceId = 611
    .OnAction = "SayHello"
End With

cb.ShowPopup

Exit_CreateCommand:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ctr = Nothing
    Set cb = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_CreateCommand:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_CreateCommand
End Sub


Sub KillCommand()
On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(sCommName).Delete
End Sub

Sub SayHello()
    MsgBox Selection.Text, vbInformation, "Hello..."
End Sub
```

> 3. Find `ThisDocument` module, copy and paste code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Close()
   Set cApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
   Set cApp = New cRightClickEventHandler
End Sub
```

This is the result when you right click:

[image]

And this is what happens when you click the custom menu item:

[image]

Hope this helps.

The original solution was found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/853460/How-to-add-custom-menu-option-in-mouse-right-click).

Comment: No, it doesn't work in my word 2016. It works in my old word 2010. :( For this reason I think there is some menu in my word 2016 which prevents the event handler from working.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It seems like they changed somenthing between Office 2013 and office 2016. If I can manage to test on 2016 I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found what happens. The event handler works perfectly with other events (window activate or double click). Therefore it seems a problem with this specific model of computer and probably the mouse drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

- Is it possible for it to make work on one word document, this seems to change for all word document active at a time.
- Rather then removing the word standard menu, can the code be changed to add as a new item on the standard rightclick menu